# Converting data to a C header as way to store as binary

Tags: c++, serialization, graphics, 3d

In graphics there is lots of talk about creating a custom binary file format for the storage of 3d assets so that more common text-based formats like OBJ and COLLADA don't have to get parsed at runtime. Makes sense.

What is not so simple however is the actual creation of this binary file, as it involves techniques like serialization or perhaps other methods, some of which are not even natively handled by C++ except maybe in its most recent variant.

But it occurred to me that if I parse one of these text-based formats into a C-style header, where the data is simply parsed into a `float` or `struct` declaration, then this data will be compiled into binary with the rest of the app. That is, the parsing is done outside the app, perhaps by a script, and then the conversion to binary is handled at compile time as a translation unit includes the header.

Is my thinking correct and how would this compare to actually creating a binary file format and going that route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thinking is absolutely correct: you can use compiler's help in converting textual representation to binary. Rather than using headers, I would put the data in a separate translation unit, and keep a fixed header with forward declarations of the data structures populated by your script:

Header:

```
// This is fixed
extern float data_array[];
extern size_t data_array_cnt;
```

CPP file:

```
// This gets generated by a script
float data_array[] = {1.2, 3.4, 5.6, 7.89 };
size_t data_array_cnt = sizeof(data_array)/sizeof(float);
```

The biggest difference between the two approaches is that keeping binary representation in a file lets you modify whatever is represented *after* you have compiled everything. In fact, you could swap in another binary in production, and it would take effect immediately. In contrast, the compiler route forces you to recompile your program every time your binary data needs to change: effectively, your binary data becomes "baked into" your program's content.

In environments that support dynamic linking you can make a middle ground solution by isolating the binary data in a separate dynamically linked library, and compiling that library separately from your "main" code. The binary data remains part of code, but now you can swap in a new piece of data independently of the rest of your program.

Comment: Can you clarify this statement: "I would use regular C/C++ files (headers would remain fixed, with forward declarations of the data structures populated by your script before the compile)."  A C header is in fact a C file, is it not? Or are you saying put the data into a translation unit, not a header file? What do you mean a header file remains "fixed" ?

Comment: @SebbyJohanns Technically, a "translation unit" already contains the headers, so you've probably misunderstood the terminology a bit. What he says is that you might put the data into a source file, not a header, so as to reduce the recompilation dependencies and / or externalize that source file into an external dynamic library.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns Please take a look at the edit with a short example.

Answer (score 0):

Compilation time etc. aside, you're screwing up the 1st, biggest and most major reason resources are packed into separate files -- they're external and swappable. Creating any kind of DLC with this header format would be almost impossible.

Your way would force a recompilation of relevant project parts every time a resource changes, whereas externalizing them moves the parsing to runtime. Artists can work on their models, textures and everything else, while developers work on the code without getting in each other's way.

Comment: what do you mean by "DLC" ?

Comment: @SebbyJohanns [Downloadable content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downloadable_content). As dasblinkenlight already said, technically you *could* link them all into a dynamic lib, but that's still ridiculously painful.

Comment: i was curious what "DLC" actually stood for but I managed to find out it meaning.